# Fluentd log driver tag setting does not work

Tags: docker, fluentd

I am using EFK stack to build a monitoring system. According to the [Docker Logging Driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/), I can add customized tag to enrich the metadata of the container log.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  watcher:
    image: image_name
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        tag: "docker/{{.ImageName}}"
    networks:
      - elastic
```

Here is my Fluent-bit configuration:

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush        5
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    debug
    Parsers_File /conf/parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name Forward
    Port 24224

[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host  elasticsearch
    Port  9200
    Index fluent_bit
    Type  json
```

As you can see, I have already add the `tag: "docker/{{.ImageName}}"` to the docker-compose file. And the container was restarted as well. The log I got in Kibana should include such a tag. But here is the log I got:

```
@timestamp:Mar 18, 2020 @ 15:35:23.000 container_id:06dde90cb998c78962e321c8396c1f992119450a6868eecb7fa14c5b348670b1 container_name:/test_container source:stderr log:2020-03-18 14:35:23 - INFO - module: __main__ - action: Watcher is started - Watcher Start _id:RmcS7nABi-qh6YwdCII3 _type:json _index:fluent_bit _score: -
```

There are still only the `container name` and `container id` in the metadata and nothing more. Can anybody tell me what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I just found where does the problem come from.

When you add a `tag` option to the log-driver, it will not be automatically included into the fluent-bit/fluentd output. The `Include_tag_key` should also be set to `true` in the output section.

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host  elasticsearch
    Port  9200
    Index fluent_bit
    Type  json
    Include_Tag_Key true
```